# Excluding a list of string using str.contains: error: nothing to repeat at position 181436

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, list

I have a list of strings that i am trying to exclude from a dataframe.

The string format are as follows:

```
Filtre=list(transactions_located.titre.unique())
```

The output is:

```
['1abcvd/C', '1abcvdee/C', '1abcvdeedd/C', '1abcvdfdfs/32', '1abcvdfadfd/C',....]
```

I am trying to exclude the strings above and create a new dataframe as follows:

```
temp=transactions.loc[~transactions['titre'].str.contains('|'.join(Filtre), case=False, na=False)]
```

I get this error:

```
error: nothing to repeat at position 181436
```

Whats wrong with my approach?  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape), because there is special regex character:

```
import re

temp=transactions.loc[~transactions['titre'].str.contains('|'.join(re.escape(x) for x in Filtre), case=False, na=False)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your suggestion outputs `print(temp.shape)`  `(0, 29)`   it should be more than that. Meaning that number of rows should be >0

Comment: @bravopapa can you check what is problematic char in `181436` row? E. g. by `transactions.loc[181436,'titre']`?

Comment: I tried `transactions[transactions['titre_origine'].str.contains('181436')])`  but the result is empty dataframe. Sorry i could not give any further hint